# Heroku Deployment, Git remote heroku not added

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I run create 'Git remote heroku added' will not appear, and I cannot push the code to gitHub. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?:

```
git remote add heroku [some url]
```

There's no such command:

```
Git remote heroku added
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the directions on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/', and when I try: $ heroku create, I get http://boiling-scrubland-4175.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:boiling-scrubland-4175.git, but no "Git remote heroku added' message, and therefore I can't keep running the tutorial